# Why does null arrays gets treated as arrays with 0 elements when passed from ajax to controller in net 7

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, .net-7.0

I am Trying to send null string array from jquery ajax call to MVC controller in NET 7

My issue is that it gets binded to an empty array (array with no elements, length 0) where I am expecting it to be null.

```
[HttpPost] 
public ActionResult Process(int employeeId, string[] yearsWorked, string reason, string     
authorizer)` 


`$('#' + freezeBtnId).on('click', function () {        
var data;
var url = '/Employee/Process';        
data = { employeeId: $('#hdnId').val(), reason: $('#txtReason').val(), authorizer:    
$('#txtAuthorizer').val()};

 $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        async: true,
        data: data, 
        success: function (data) {
            alert('success');
        }
});
```

I used chrome DEV tool and I see jquery is not sending it in the payload. I dont see yearsWorked

Please note: I am using System.Text.Json.
I am not sure  need any more configuration

```
.AddJsonOptions(options =>
                          {
                              options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true;
                              options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null;
                          });
```

I tried to specify the ContentType to "application/json" and the dataType: "json" with no success`

Comment: Try `string[]? yearsWorked`. But in general I'm not sure how and it works at all, `employeeId`, `reason` and `authorizer` should be query string parameters and you seem to pass everything in body . Can you please provide a [mre]? At least your server set up.

Comment: `string[]` is not nullable, so won't be null

Comment: @freedomn-m, I ran the same Test in net4.8 and received null.

Comment: .net4.8 isn't .net7core.  Nullable reference types added in .net core 6: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references   That's like saying "my code worked in VB6" - net4.8 and netcore7 are different languages.  They're highly similar and in 90%+ of the time work the same, but they are not the same.  Here's an example where they're different.  There's no point saying "but it worked in a previous version".

Comment: @GuruStron, my requirments is to send them in body due to some limitation to the length. I tried to string[]? with no luck. what do you mean by the server setup. Startup Configure Services ?

Comment: @Mikey yes, something which could be run and tested.